# Is it possible to automatically back up a mac to two different time capsules (in different locations)

Tags: macos, backup, osx-leopard, time-machine

Can Time Machine automatically back up to two different timecapsules, one at home and one at the office for example?

Comment: That's a good question! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sort of. You need to click the "Change Disk" option in Time Machine's Pref Pane each time you are in a new location.

If you want it to be automated, that is more involved. Macosxhints has more info [here](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20090603163307642) and [here](http://www.macosxhints.com/comment.php?mode=view&cid=106493).

Another option is to have Time Machine at one location and have SuperDuper make a clone automatically each night at the other.

Comment: Awesome, thank you, I looked on Macosxhints and, in addition to your links, found this post ( http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20080105135511764 ) which talks about using DSW and applescript to change the drive automatically.

Comment: Be aware that some of those articles were pre-Time Capsule to they may work with hard drives but you might run into problems with Time Capsules. Let us know if it works and post your solution for others.